# Hosting modal WPF dialog in Win32 application

Tags: c#, c++, wpf, dialog, modal-dialog

I'm trying to invoke a modal WPF dialog from a dialog of a Win32 application on the press of a button but everytime after invoking the dialog, if I try to minimize and maximize the application (or any other activity that makes the application lose focus), the dialog gets hidden behind the application.

I'm calling the `dialog.Activate()` method to invoke the dialog activated and on top and it also seems modal in the sense that I can't interact with the Win32 dialog that invoked it nor the Win32 application itself. But once the app loses focus, the WPF dialog goes behind the application.

I could see the same problem on invoking the WPF dialog from a WPF application as well but am easily able to resolve it by setting the `dialog.Owner` property of the WPF dialog to the dialog invoking it but I'm not sure how I can do it from a Win32 application. I've written a C++/CLI wrapper around my WPF dialog and I'm using it in my Win32 app to invoke the WPF dialog. I thought of setting the Owner property through the wrapper but I'm not sure how I can set a Win32 dialog window as the owner of a `System.Windows.Window` dialog.

Comment: Apps don't own windows, windows own windows. Pass a handle (`HWND`) to the managed code, and set it as the owner.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I used the WindowInteropHelper class to set the Owner of the WPF dialog and it works well as far as modality of the dialog goes. I did notice though that the WPF dialog gets invoked at the top left corner of the screen even though I've set its Startup location as CenterOwner. I'm currently using Windows method : GetTopWindow(GetActiveWindow()) to get the HWND of the invoking dialog. I'll probably post some code on how I achieved the modal dialog behavior once I figure out how to invoke the WPF dialog at the center of the invoking dialog.